# record http request process time in play framework2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm developing an application with play framework in java, in order to evaluate the performance of my application, I want to record the time on processing each http request. Based on the official document provided, I can only find one place in Global.java, where I can override the onRequest method to record the start time of a request.
 Is there any plugin or hooks in this framework so I can add my code like this way?

```
long start = System.getsystem.currenttimemillis(); processRequest(request); long end = System.getsystem.currenttimemillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Filters. There is a working example which is exactly what you are looking for.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters